# Keep distance between 2 out of 3 elements equal when scaling window (responsive)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

There are 2 img div's on top of each-other, next to a fluid header logo (.svg) also in a div.

The HTML:

```
<header class="site-header" role="banner" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader"><div class="wrap"><div id="menu_container"><img src="http://95.85.63.245/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/images/Hamburger_optimized.svg" alt="menu"  class="menu-btn" /><div class="menu_spacer"></div><img src="http://95.85.63.245/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/images/searchicon.png" alt="zoek"  class="search_icon" /></div>


<div class="title-area"><h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://95.85.63.245/"></a></h1></div><div class="vr_menu_logo"><a href="/"><img src="http://95.85.63.245/wp-content/uploads/dynamik-gen/theme/images/logo_VR_font.svg"></a></div>
</div></header>
```

The CSS:

```
.vr_menu_logo{
  max-width:95%; 
  float:left;
  margin-right:20px;
  }

#menu_container {
  max-width: 5%;
  float: right;
  }

  .menu-btn{
 cursor: pointer;
 max-height: 30px;
 max-width: 30px;
 margin-top:2em;
}

.menu_spacer{height:4em;}

.search_icon{
  cursor: pointer;
  max-height: 24px;
  max-width: 24px;
  }


.site-header .wrap {
  width: 1260px;
  }
.site-header .wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Goal: 
Scaling the browser window would keep the small hamburger and the search icon's on level with respectively the top and bottom of the logo. Actually the 3 seperate items should act as one logo.
[image]

Check the cssdesk here: http://www.cssdesk.com/JDyYQ

I was hoping a spacer div with a max-height would do the trick, or display:table-cell; 
But I can't get it to work, anyone have an idea? (javascript can be an option too, but this must be possible with CSS I would think...)

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using `flexbox` - note in the fiddle that the two `div` are exactly the same apart from having a different `height`. This should help you getting what you are trying to achieve. Obviously check what kind of browser support you need to provide as flexbox is a relatively new technology.

http://jsfiddle.net/zn50mmnu/

[image]

html:

```
<div class="flexy f1">
    <span class="menu">M</span>
    <span class="search">S</span>
</div>
<div class="flexy f2">
    <span class="menu">M</span>
    <span class="search">S</span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.flexy {
    float: right;
    clear: both;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 2px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}

.f1 {
    height: 50px;
}

.f2 {
    height: 90px;
}

.menu {
    background: red;
    width: 1em;
}

.search {
    background: blue;
    width: 1em;
}
```

Comment: flexbox doesn't have a wide enough browser support to be used yet imo

Comment: like, IE8 and 9? http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox - you can always fall-back for those, if they are to be supported. While it's true that the coverage is not 100%, Flexbox right now is working in all modern browsers (IE9 isn't one)

Comment: Yes indeed, but adding fallback will not fix his issue for the browsers IE 8 and 9, and when you are a windowsuser and you use Safari, you'll use the Safari 5, wich also in not working correctly with flexbox.
I think flexbox, should only be used in intranets when you can tell the users witch browsers to use.

Comment: Thanks Luca. I'm gonna give flexbox a try. I agree that people with older browsers just have bad luck. Then they should upgrade to chrome, FF or other.

Comment: I'm a bit suprised it is not possible with traditional CSS by the way. 
Is there really not a way to have one container with a large div (logo) sticking left and the two smaller div's (menu + search ) sticking to the right top and right bottom of the container?

Comment: @sjoerdvh yes, there are alternative ways in css, e.g. using absolute positioning, however you will need to pay more attention to other factors (positioned DOM elements overlapping, rendering issues on some mobile browsers)

Comment: they make perfect sense :)
It's not a good practise to use it in it's state.
Everybody should know what it is, and how to use it, but not use it in it's state.